# VirtualBox doesn't see Wireless USB Adapter

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, virtualbox

So I run Ubuntu 14.04 as my main OS, I have VirtualBox installed which was from the Software Centre, what I am trying to do is add my Alfa AWUS051NH Dual Band 802.11a/b/g/n WiFi Wireless-N USB Adapter to my Linux BackBox installation.

I've read that all is needed is to add the USB under Settings then Add USB but this doesn't work for me, it says "no devices available".

Can anyone help me to add and get this Adapter working under VirtualBox?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give yourself the rights to access the USB devices. Just follow the [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB).

Comment: Adding to the usergroup then rebooting did the trick.